# Suggestions on GPU accelerating my coin miner?

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins

Wanting to get in on the ground floor of this new cryptocurrency, I wrote myself a simple miner:

```shell
sleep 3 # I'm slow moving the mouse to the Window. Sorry.
while true
    do xte 'mouseclick 1'
    sleep 0.$((RANDOM%2))$((RANDOM%10)) # random is more fun
done
```

but I can't figure out how to get a CUDA port to work. Every time I try, the GPU's fast clicking vibrates it out of the PCIe socket. I've tried tightening the retaining screw, but I can only get it so tight before it strips the screw.

Comment: Off-topic, belongs on Stack Overflow.  Oh, wait.

Comment: Apply more thermal paste. That thing should be slathered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known deficiency in the free driver. It doesn't support the socket power dampener properly, which leads to oscillation. Install the proprietary driver, and don't forget to activate the CUDA port in udev.

Answer (score 0):

Swearing profusely and applying lots of duct tape fixes most issues.

(I've had bad results when using this technique on people, though.)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Maybe because my mining rig doesn't have a microphone attached?